# java extract elements separated by comma from a String

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
String input= 'hello',2,[5,6],'city'.
```

So the string is composed by different kind of elements.

I "simply" need to extract the elements separated by comma. However i cannot find
a method to avoid to consider the comma into the element `[5,6]`.
I tried by using the split() method and considering many different regex to
reach my goal, without success.

Comment: Provided input is not valid string should be wrapped in literals (double quotes)

Comment: `str.split(",(?![^\\[\\]]*\\])")`, [demoooo](https://regex101.com/r/wKVhqc/1)

Comment: If you are dealing with CSV, get a CSV parser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`,(?![^\[]*[]])` works for the job.

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){

        String test = "'hello',2,[5,6],'city'";
        String[] output = test.split(",(?![^\\[]*[]])");

        for (String s : output)
            System.out.println(s);

    }
}
```

Output:

```
'hello'
2
[5,6]
'city'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Can i ask you how works this regex? it's not so clear for me the text within the round brackets.

Comment: @Marco < I can only offer you [the book](https://www.amazon.com/dp/1787288706/?tag=stackoverfl08-20) to comprehend what the regex and its variations do.